# StarUML defining interface methods and attributes in the interface icon?

Tags: uml, tool-uml

I'm just using StarUML to create my UML Class diagram and something is bothering me. I create an interface representation, which is a circle, however, there is no room to add which methods and attributes the interface defines. Is this normal UML practice?

If not, how do you know (say a class implements this interface and has 4 methods defined) which of the 4 methods came from the interface and which didnt?

Solved:

Ok just incase someone else has this problem- there are two notations, both are possible in StarUML but only one explicitly (the dot notation). To create the <> notation, enter the name as <> IInterface_Name and then draw a realisation line between the implementing classes. Be sure to manually delete the old (wrong) relationship you had by right clicking the class, collection editor and then relations.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is very simple:

1. If you need just show method of interface - right click on interface and un-select Format/Suppress operation (see blue circle on picture)
2. If you need to display instead of circle just squared form of interface (on my picture it is ISome) use Format/Stereotype Display/Decoration (see red circle on picture bellow)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i found another way- just to show the non-dot notation method, along with a realisation association

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue and didn't know you could change the shape.  However it won't let me add any method declarations to the Interface. I've tried 'Add > Operation' but it just does nothing. How did you add the Operation2 to your ISome?
I'm using v2.0.0 mac.

Comment: DOH! You already answered that in point 1. I hadn't unticked Suppress Operations. Serious case of RTFSO.

Comment: Coming a bit too late to the party but wondered if it is possible to make it default interface to be drawn in squared <<interface>> shape... This should be standard no? I was surprised to see circle for interface

Comment: @Ewoks may be I don't get you question right, but if mean "Can I change <<interface>> onto smthng else" - then yes, you can. It is called stereotype. For some reason StarUML allows modify it for regular classes, but Interfaces are displayed with fixed

Comment: on your screenshot I see it under menu as circle, and next to it,not covered ISome with Operation2(), is how I would expect interface to be represented by default (instead of default circle that StarUML offers)

Comment: @Ewoks - yes, go to Menu\Tools\Options, select Environment\Specific View and scroll to "Interface View". For my version I can see "Show Stereotype = Icon" (or whatever you select)